# Walking to space

Tags: hard-science, atmosphere

Is it possible to have any kind of natural celestial body where at some point on it it's capable of supporting human life without technological assistance (breathable air, survivable temperature with a coat at most, survivable pressure) yet have some point of it that's outside said body atmosphere so one could in theory walk to space?

The way I'm imagining it is some very very deep cavern that holds all of the planet atmosphere (doesn't have to be more then a single room sized area at the bottom of it that's in the "goldielocks zone") yet once you walk the thousands of step outside said cavern your technically in space as your outside the body atmosphere, I don't care if the journey will be years of walking uphill or that once upside the very small starting area you can't survive without a spacesuit, my question is that possible?

Comment: Do you want this atmosphere to hold on for geological amount of time?

Comment: @Alexander yes.

Comment: Your looking for a space elevator, without the elevator, so space stairs then? possible according to some as an artificial structure, though even they admit the materials with the required tolerances haven't been invented yet, impossible as a natural feature though I think., but natural or artificial you're going to have to anchor it with something in geosynchronous orbit or it will simply collapse, if not immediately then in pretty short order (aka a timeframe significantly shorter than anything considered geological).

Comment: @Cypher  I have started an answer discussing the problem and suggesting solitions.  I will add to it later in Sept. 23, 2021.

Comment: @Cypher   On 10-21-21, I added a lot more incluiding several more recomendations to my answer of 23 Sept. 2021.

Answer (score 3):

"The way I'm imagining it is some very very deep cavern that holds all of the planet atmosphere (doesn't have to be more then a single room sized area at the bottom of it that's in the "goldielocks zone") yet once you walk the thousands of step outside said cavern your technically in space as your outside the body atmosphere, I don't care if the journey will be years of walking uphill or that once upside the very small starting area you can't survive without a spacesuit, my question is that possible?"

From my understanding this is the most realistic understanding of this idea. I've heard it said that if we terraformed Mars, the bottom of Valles Marineris would be the first place that had breathable air as the process continued.

From my understanding however of your example, such a thing isn't really "space," it is simply walking from breathable air to a vacuum. On Earth we can do this to some extent when we climb mountains.

You might consider some world where you can climb a gigantic mountain like Olympus Mons on Mars - though Olympus Mons formed under very specific circumstances, and may not work the same way if most of the planet it is on is habitable.

At a certain point with building mountains to space, it doesn't work, as gravity wants planets to be round. This to my knowledge is actually happening with Olympus Mons, as it it is so tall at something like 5 miles high, that it and other tall mounts on Mars are being pulled apart kind of (I'm not sure if that's exactly what's happening.)

It seems the easiest way for your concept to occur is with some amount of human intervention. Maybe you have a planet that has such plentiful deposits of breathable gases that the humans don't have any qualms about venting them out of their caverns.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. Oh my did I get that totally wrong? Oh dang it, I did. WIkipedia says 13.6 mi (21.9 km), but regardless which is accurate, thank you for the correction.

Comment: You're correct in the comment, my error.

Comment: The hard science tag requires answers with evidence & citations, so some links are expected.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that what you ask for is impossible to last in the long run.  Impossible with a direct connection between breathable atmosphere and vacuum and without areas where the atmospheric density gradually decreases from dense enough to support human life to thin and vacuum enough to statisfy the question.

Suppose that a spaceship lands in a deep crater on the Moon, and air leaks out of the spaceship.  The air might form a breathable atmosphere at the bottom of the crater, but it will be escaping from the crater until all the air in ship is gone, and then the air at the bottom of the crater will gradually dissipate.

Of course the crew of the spacesip could patch all the leaks in their spaceship and save some of their air supply.  But the air in the crater bottom outside will eventually dissipate.

Any situation where there is a vacuum and a breathable atmosphere, and an opening between them, will eventually result in the breathable atmosphere escaping into the vacuum and becoming as thin as the vacuum.  The only thing which can save the breathable atmosphere is closing the opening.

And then you will have the equivlaent of a moon base with breathable atmosphere inside and an airlock which people have to use to go outside in space suits to the vacuum of space.  Which of course is very common in science fiction and not a rare or unique situation.  Real people have actually done the equivalent, getting out of spaceships that were landed on the Moon, and going on spacealks from orbiting spacecraft.

Long Answer:

There is some hope.

If there was a mountain a hundred miles, or even maybe a hundred kilometers, tall on Earth, somewhere wearing a spaceshuit could climb up to the top and be in an atmosphere that was so thin that it would be a vacuum for all practical purposes. The Karmen Line is an official boundry between Earth's atmosphere and the vacuum of outer space, placed at a height of 100 kilometers above sea level.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%c3%a1rm%c3%a1n_line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A1rm%C3%A1n_line)

So if you can create a situation where there is breathable atmosphere at the very lowest point on a planet, and air as thin as at the Karmen Line at the highest point of the planet, you cn claim there is breathable air and the vacuum of outer space on different parts of the surface of your planet, using an definition of outer space officially adopted by some organizations.

I wonder how the atmospheric density at the Karmen Line compares with the thinnest vacuums produced in scientific labs.

The Challenger Deep in the Mariana Trench is the lowest point on the surface of Earth, being 10,920 m (35,827 ft) ±10 m (33 ft), 10.920 kilometers or 6.78 miles below sea level at its lowest point, far deeper than any mines or known natural caverns on Earth.  The summit of Mount Everest is the point on Earth highest above sea level, at 8,848.86 m (29,031.7 ft) 8.848 Kilomters or 5.49 miles, according to the most recent determinaiton in 2020.

So the total elevation difference on present day Earth is 19,768.86 meters, or 19.76886 kilometers, or 64,858.7 feet, or 12.283844 miles.

I suppose that what you need is a planet with an atmosphere which decreases rapidly with height.

> In various scientific contexts, a scale height, usually denoted by the capital letter H, is a distance over which a quantity decreases by a factor of e (the base of natural logarithms, approximately 2.718).

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_height#:~:text=The%20earth%20atmosphere%27s%20scale%20height%20is%20about%208.5km%2C,is%20about%201000%2C%20370%2C%20and%20140%20hPa%2C%20respectively.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_height#:%7E:text=The%20earth%20atmosphere%27s%20scale%20height%20is%20about%208.5km%2C,is%20about%201000%2C%20370%2C%20and%20140%20hPa%2C%20respectively.)

The article gives examples of the scale heights of the atmopsheres of various planets in our solar system.

You want the scale height of your planet to be as short as possible, so that a mountain with a plausible or possible height can stick up to altitudes where there isn't a vacuum, but the air is so thin and unbreathable that people need to wear not merely oxygen masks, like in the "death zones" of tall mountains on Earth, but actual full body pressurized environmental suits similar to space suits.

The scale heights of the planetary atmospheres in the solar system vary greatly.  The giant planets should have high surface gravities at their solid surfaces - if any - far below their cloud layers,  and those high surface gavitie should act tocompress their atmosheres and give them low scale heights.  But the scale heights of the giant planets are actually quite high, because their atmospheres are mostly composed of Hydrogen and helium, which are not very dense.

The atmospheres, if any, of more solid bodies should have lower scale heights, and that is the case with the atmospheres of Venus, Earth, Mars, and Titan.

Earth has the shortest scale height of any known solar system body, because it has the highest surface gravity of the solid bodies, as well as an stmosphere less dense than that of Titan, and much less dense than that of Venus.

The scale height of Earth's atmosphere is 8.5 kilometers, which is about 0.429 of 19.76886 kilometers.  The greeatest elevatio difference on Earth is about 2.3 times the scale height of the atmosphere.

The scale height of an atmosphere is the height at which density decreases by about 2.718.  So if all the ocean water was removed from Earth, the atmospheric density at the bottom of the Challenger deep should be a bit more than about 7.38 times as dense as the atmospheric pressure at the summit of Mount Everest, and the atmosphereic pressure at the summit of Mount Everest will be only 0.135 times what it will be at the lowest point of the Challenger Deep.

And of course you don't have to make the atmospheric pressure at the bottom of the Challenger Deep equivalent on your desert planet as high as the sea level pressure on Earth.  You can make it as low as humans can endure, changing the percentages of various gases to get the minimum possible pressure. If you make the composiiton and density on the lowest point on your planet as low as humans can sefealy breath, the pressure at the top of your Mount Everest equivalent will be only 0.135 times that lesser density, and so somewhat closer to the vacuum you desire.

Humans can survive breathing an atmosphere of almost pure oxygen.  They need some water vapor in the atmosphere, and the plants that grow on a habitable planet (or in the tiny habitable section of your fictional planet) would need some nitrogen and carbon dioxode in the air.

The first place I think of to find the limits of atmosphere breathable for humans is *Habitable Planets for Man*, Stephen H. Dole, 1964.

https://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/commercial_books/2007/RAND_CB179-1.pdf

Chapter Two: Human Requirements has a section "Atmospheric Pressure and Composition" on pages 13 to 19.

> To summarize, then, the atmosphere of a habitable planet must contain oxygen with an inspired partial pressure between 60 and 400 milimeters of mercury and carbon dioxide with a pressure roughly between about 0.05 and 7 millimeters of mercury. In addition, the partial pressures of the inert gases must be below certain specified limits, and the toxic gases must not be present in more than trace amounts.  Some nitrogren must be present so that nitrogen in combined form can find its way into plants.

So a breathable atmosphere for humans should have acompined pressure of oxygen and carbon dioxide (almost entirely oxygen) between roughly 60.05 and 407 millimeters of mercury, as well as some nitrogren.

So a planet could probably have an atmospheric pressue as low as 70 millimeters of mercury if that atmosphere was almost entirely oxygen but contained a little carbon dioxide, water vapor, and nitrogen.

So if you have an atmospheric pressure of 70 millimeters of mercury at the bottom of your Challenger Deep equivalent, the atmospheric pressure at the summit of your Mount Everest equivalent will be only about 0.135 times that, or about 9.95 millimeters of mercury.

> Atmospheric pressure, also known as barometric pressure (after the barometer), is the pressure within the atmosphere of Earth. The standard atmosphere (symbol: atm) is a unit of pressure defined as 101,325 Pa (1,013.25 hPa; 1,013.25 mbar), which is equivalent to 760 mm Hg, 29.9212 inches Hg, or 14.696 psi.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A1rm%C3%A1n_line) The atm unit is roughly equivalent to the mean sea-level atmospheric pressure on Earth; that is, the Earth's atmospheric pressure at sea level is approximately 1 atm.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_pressure

So one atmosphere pressure is equal to about 1,013.25 mbar or 760 millimeters of mercury.  So there are about 1.3332236 mbar per millimeter of mercury (mm HG), or 0.7500616 millimeters of mercury (mm HG) per mbar.

So on a hypothetical Earth without any seawater, if the pressure at the bottom of the Challenger Deep was only 70 millimeters of mercury or 93.325652 mbar, the pressure at the summit of Mount Everest would be about 9.95 millimeters of mercury or 13.265574 mbar.

Using a Karmen line at 100 kilometers, that would be about 11.76 times the scale height of the Earth's atmosphere.  If atmospheric density decreases by a 2.718 factor for each scale height, at an altitude of 11 scale heights the atmospheric pressure would be 1 divided by 2.718 to the 11th power, and at an altitude of 12 scale heights the atmospheric pressure would be 1 sea level pressure divided by 2.715 to the 12th pressure.

2.718 to the 11th power is about 59,805.89, and 2.718 to the 12th power is about 162,552.416.  So the atmospheric pressure at 11 scale heights or about 93.5 kilometers, would be about 0.0169 mbar, and the atmospheric pressure at 12 scale heights, about 102 kilometers, would be about 0.0062333 mbar.

The calculated atmospheric pressure at the summit of Mount Everest if the deepest part of the Challenger Deep had an atmosphere barely dense enough to support human life was calculated to be about 13.265574 mbar, which is 784.955 to 2,128.1783 times the pressure at a Karmen line calculated to be at 100 kilometers.

So if an atmospheric denesity as low as 13.265574 mbar is not low enough to seem like outer space to you, you have a problem.

Later I will try to find ways to solve that problem or see what the limits of solving it would be.

Added 1:11 Am EDT Sept 23 2021.

Ways to require a less extrme pressure difference between the densest part of the atmosphere and the summit of the tallest mountain on the planet.

As I wrote above, the absolute minimum pressure of an atmosphere breathable for humans would be oxygen and a little carbon dioxide totalling about 60.05 millimeters of mercury (mmHg), or about 80.060077 mbar.

And assuming that addditonal amounts of water vapor and nitrogen would be needed, and they would bring the pressure up to about 70 millimiters of mercury at the lowest spot on a waterless Earth duplicate, the pressure at the top of the Mount Everest equivalent would be about 9.95 millimeters of mercury or 13.265574 mbar.

And that would be many thousands of times as dense as the pressure at the Karmen line.

But suppose that the pressure at the bottom could be only 69 millimeters of mercury, or 68, or something, and still have enough water vapor and nitrogren to support life.

And suppose that the Karmen line between the upper atmosphere and outer space is lower than 100 kilometers for some purposes.  Using such a lower Karmen line would have a higher atmospheric pressure at the border of outer space.

Some people today consider that the boundry between the atmosphere and outer space should be at 80 kilometers or 50 miles.

80 kilometers is 9.411 times the scale height of Earth's atmosphere.  At an altitude of 9 times the scale height the pressure would be about 1013.25 mbar divided by 8,095.525993, or about 0.125 mbar. At an altitude of 10 times the scale height the atmospheric pressuer would be about 0.0460492 mbar.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%c3%a1rm%c3%a1n_line#Alternatives_to_the_FAI_definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A1rm%C3%A1n_line#Alternatives_to_the_FAI_definition)

I note that 8 times 8.5 is 68.  An altitude of 68 kilometers would be about 8 times the scale height of Earth's atmosphere and would have a pressure of about 0.3401895 mb.

And I think that is about as low, if not lower, than anyone would think of putting the Karmen Line between the atmosphere and outer space.

Combining a higher pressure at a lower Karmen Line with a lower pressure at the summit of the highest peak gives a much sammler difference.

A pressure of of 69 millipmeters of mercury (mm Hg) or 91.99229 mbar in the lowest depression gives a pressure of 12.418 mbar at the Summitt of the highest mountain, which is 267.09971 times the pressure at 10 times the scale height.

A pressure of 68 mm hg or 90.659 mbar at the lowest point would give a pressure of about 12.2389 mbar at the highest peak, which is about 265.778 times the pressure at 10 scale heights.

A pressure of 67 mm Hg or 89.3259 mbar at the lowest point would give a pressure of about 12.0590007 mbar at the highest peak, which is about 261.87223 times the pressure at 10 scale heights.

A pressure of 66 mm Hg or 87.9927 mbar at the lowest point would give a pressure of about 11.879 mbar at the highest peak, which is about 95.032 times the pressure at 9 scale heights.

A pressure of 65 mm Hg or 86.659 mbar at the lowest point would give a pressure of about 11.699 mbar at the highest peak, which is about 93.59 times the pressure at 9 scale heights.

A pressure of 64 mm Hg or 85.3263 mbar at the lowest point would give a pressure of about 11.519 mbar at the highest peak, which is about 92.152 times the pressure at 9 scale heights.

A pressure of 63 mm Hg or 83.993 mbar at the lowest point would give a pressure of about 11.339 mbar at the highest peak, which is about 33.33 times the pressure at 8 scale heights.

A pressure of 62 mm Hg or 82.659 mbar at the lowest point would give a pressure of about 11.159 mbar at the highest peak, which is about 32.8025 times the pressure at 8 scale heights.

A pressure of 61 mm Hg or 81.13266 mbar at the lowest point would give a pressure of about 10.979 mbar at the highest peak, which is about 32.273 times the pressure at 8 scale heights.

So these somewhat slight changes in definition make the problem much less formidable.

I suppose that if humans accustomed to the air at high altitudes settle on a  planet with an atmospheric pressure near the lower limit of human endurance, after many generations of selective pressure (or genetic modifications) some of them should be able to tolerate significantly lower pressure, and might settle on an planet witheven lower pressure, and so on and so on over many thousands of years, pruducing races of humans with progressively lower atmospheric pressure requirements.

How low could they go?

I don't know.  I don't think they could get much lower than about 61 mm Hg or about 81.3266 mbar, but I am certan there are people much better qualified than me to discuss that.

There seems to be a lower pressure limit at the Armstrong limit

> The Armstrong limit or Armstrong's line is a measure of altitude above which atmospheric pressure is sufficiently low that water boils at the normal temperature of the human body. Exposure to pressure below this limit results in a rapid loss of consciousness, followed by a series of changes to cardiovascular and neurological functions, and eventually death, unless pressure is restored within 60–90 seconds.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A1rm%C3%A1n_line) On Earth, the limit is around 18–19 km (11–12 mi; 59,000–62,000 ft) above sea level,[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_height#:%7E:text=The%20earth%20atmosphere%27s%20scale%20height%20is%20about%208.5km%2C,is%20about%201000%2C%20370%2C%20and%20140%20hPa%2C%20respectively.) above which atmospheric air pressure drops below 0.0618 atm (6.3 kPa, 47 mmHg, or about 1 psi). The U.S. Standard Atmospheric model sets the Armstrong pressure at an altitude of 63,000 feet (19,202 m).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armstrong_limit

So the Armstrong limit is about 47 mmHg, or about 62.66 mbar.  And possibly the people in your story have evolved someone lower normal body temperatures and so could tolerate slightly lower pressures.

Although I am sceptical that humans will ever be able to tolerate atmospheric pressue even as low as 47 mm Hg, let alone lower.  How could they get enough oxygen at such lowe presures?

If people could breath in an atmospheric pressure of about 62.66 mbar at the Challenger Deep equivalent of a planet, the Mount Everest equivalent would have a pressure of about 8.459 mbar, which would be 24.895 times the pressure at the lowest possible Karmen line at 8 scale heights of Earth's atmosphere.

Of course you could define the border of the vacuum of outer space for the purposes of your story as being at the Armstrong limit. If the summit of your world's Mount Everest equivalent has an atmosphereic pressure of about 62.66 mbar, the Armstrong limit, its Challenger Deep equivalent would have a pressure of about 464.148 mbar, which is much higher than the minimum pressure needed by humans.

If the Challenger Deep equivalent has a pressure of about 93 or 94 mbar, about as low as humans could breath, the summit of the Mount Everest equivalent would have a pressure of about 12.555 to 12.69 mbar, much lower than the Armstrong limit.

Of course some definiitons of the edge of Earth's atmosphere and the beginning of outer space place it tens, hundreds, or thousands of kilometers higher than the Armstrong limit or the Karmen line, where the atomspheric density is much, much, thinner than at those altitudes.   You don't want to  use those definitions in your story.

Recommendaition Number One:

Make your definition of the edge of the vacuum of outer space to be at the Armstrong limit instead of at the Karmen line.  Even though there will still be noticable atmospheric effects at the Armstrong limit.   Thus a planet like a dry planet Earth would have more than enough relief to have a breathable atmosphere at its Challenger Deep equivalent and air as thin as at the Armstrong limit and edge of outer space at its equivalent of the summit of MOunt Everest.

Recomendation Number Two:

Use the Karmen Line, at about 8 to 12 times the scale height of an atmosphere with Earthlike pressure at the bottom, as the border of outer space, but make the altitude differences on your planet high enough to have a thinner atmosphere than Earth's but still breathable, at the lowest point, and at least one summit at or above the Karmen line equivalent.

So you need to find ways to make the elevation differences on your planet several more multiples of the scale height of its atmosphere than they are on Earth.

Recommendation Number Two A:

Make a planet that is not perfectly spherical, with a normal diameter of, for example, 10,000 kilometers, but with a protusion of 100 kilometers in one area.  That protusion will be only one percent of the normal diameter of hte planet and barely visible to the human eye when looking at the planet as a whole, but it will be enough to have Earth's sea level atmospheric pressure on most parts of the surface and the highest point reaching the Karmen line and the vacuum of space by one definition.

After all, many asteroids and small moons have potato like shapes and many are 2 or 3 times as long in one dimension as in another, a much greater deviation from a perfect sphere.

Bu the larger and more massive an astronomical object is, the stronger its gravity will pull on its matter.  The matter at the center of the object will become soft and flow into as nearly spherical a shape as it can, and the uncompressed matter at the surface will rest on that spherical shape and form a roughly spherical outer layer around it.

Objects mostly made of ice will become spherical at a smaller size than objects made mostly of rock which will become spherical at a smaller size than objects made mostly of metal.  And the precise limits are not known.  But objects with a radius of no more than 1,000 kilometers are almost certain to become close to spherical in shape, and some much smaller aobjects are spherical.

So what is the smallest size of a planet capable of retaining a breathable atmosphere?

That is discussed in *Habitable Planets for Man*, Stephen H. Dole, 1964.

https://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/commercial_books/2007/RAND_CB179-1.pdf

Chapter Two: Human Requirements has  a section Gravity, about the gravitational requirements of humans, on pages 11 to 13.  On page 12 Dole concludes that:

> On the basis of the available data, one might conclude that few people would choose to live on a planet were the surface gravity was greater than 1.25 or 1.50 *g*.

Chapter Four: the astronomical Parameters has a section on planetary properties on pages 53 to 67.

Dole says that a habitable planet should not have a surface grvity more than 1.50 *g*, which corresponds to a planet with a mass of 2.35 earth masses, a radius of 1.25 Earth radii, and an escape velocity of 15.3 kilometers per second.

What is the lower mass limit for a planet capable of retaining a breathable atmosphere?

That depends on the ratio between the escape velocity of the planet divided by the root-mean-square velocity of the atmospheric molecules and atoms at the temperature in the outermost layer of the planet's atmosphere.

Table 6 on page 37 shows that if the ratio is 1 or 2 atmsopheric excape will e almost instantaneous.  If the ratio is 3 escape will take a few weeks, if the ratio is 4 escape will take thousands of years, if the ratio is 5 escape will take about a hundred million years, and if the ratio is 6 escape will take a more or less infinite time.

So on page 54 Dole concludes that a planet with an escape velocity as low as 6.25 kilomeers per second can retain a breathable atmosphere for a long time.  Such planet would have a mass of 0.195 Earth mass, a radius of 0.63 Earth Radii, and a surface gravity of 0.49 *g*.

Such a planet would have a radius 0.63 that of Earth's 6,371 Kilometers, or 4,013.73 kilometers, and a diameter of 8027.46 kilometers, and thus have hundreds of times the minimum mass to squeeze its interior into a spherical shape.

[added 09-23-2021.  But Dole didn't believe that a planet that small could produce an oxygen rich atmosphere.  Dole calculated 2 different figures for hte minimum mas of a planet that could produce an oxygen rich atmosphere, 0.25mass Earth and 0.57 mass Earth.  Dole more or less arbitarilly selected 0.4 times the msss of Earth as the minimum mass of apalenet that could produce an oxygen-rich atmosphere.  Such a planet would have a radius of 0.78 Earth radius and a surface gravity of 0.68 *g*.}

[added 09-23-2021 My answer to the question https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/41590/can-a-habitable-planet-be-smaller-than-0-58-earth-radii/41599#41599   mentions several more modern estimates for the minimum mass of a habitable planet, moon or other world.  Some of those extimates might be for worlds without oxygen rich atmspheres necessary for humans.  in any case those estimates don't take the minimum mass much closer to a mass where a planet could have a highly irregular shape.]

On Earth, a mountain much taller than Everest would start to flow and slump under its own weight, and become lower.  The stronger the rock or other material a mountain is made of, the higher it can be without deforming unde rits own weight.  But stronger materials are usually denser ones. If a mountain is made of much denser matter than the ground underneath it, that ground will flow away from under the mountain, and the mountain will sink lower into the ground.

Thus it is hard to make a mountain several times taller than Everest on a planet like Earth.  And the minimum sized planet to have a breathable atmosphere seems to be large enough to be only a little bit different from Earth in that respect.

https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/9745/how-high-can-a-mountain-possibly-get

[added 09-23-2021   And if a valley is low enough, it will reach more or less liquid materials within the mantle of the Earth, and it will take the pressure of kilometers of heavy material above off of that more or less liquid material below.  So the more or less liquid material will gradually ooze up and partially fill the deep valley, putting a limit on how deep a valley can get.]

But don't give up, I will add some more suggestions later  In Partt Two of my anser.

Answer (score 1):

## Sorry, no.

Human habitability means that you're basically talking about the Earth.

Larger planets with identical surface gravity would have a deeper gravitational well and be an even more impossible proposition; smaller bodies would require higher densities, and there's a hard natural limit to that (just four times Earth's: the density of osmium).

On Earth, you would need a hundred-kilometer high mountain to reach the boundary of space.

Now a mountain is a pile of material and the material at the bottom has to hold all the material on top; but at pressures above their *elastic limit*, materials start flowing, and behave like a liquid. That's why, incidentally, planets are spheres. They're actually enormous *drops* of material made "liquid-ish" by its own weight, that starts flowing like a glacier, for the same reason.

The elastic limit (Young's modulus) for most rocks is in the 10<sup>11</sup> Pascal range [[table]](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Youngs-Modulus-for-chosen-rocks_tbl1_326137046), which gives a maximum height for a mountain under Earth gravity of around 12-15 km depending on its density - [this](https://websites.pmc.ucsc.edu/%7Efnimmo/eart163/Week2-Rheology.pdf) is a pretty comprehensive presentation.

Approximating the mountain with a cone, we have

[image]

There is no *natural* material and process that can yield a 100-km high mountain: the "core", under maximum stress, would start flowing out, cracking the mountain and making it collapse.

You would need a "bubbly" mountain, which could be much less dense; a density of one tenth normal rock, and therefore below even that of pumice (300 kg/m<sup>3</sup>), would allow a mountain ten times the height of Everest. But there's no natural process that could produce and amass such a shape in sintered rock bubbles.

You can do something that using a much denser "atmosphere" (e.g. a water atmosphere: that exists in nature -- it's an ocean). Then yes, you can walk on the bottom of the breathable sea until you come ashore and leave your "atmosphere" to enter the world of gases (this happens in a story by James Blish, *Surface Tension*).

Comment: The hard science tag requires answers with evidence & citations, so some links are expected.

Answer (score 0):

**No it is not possible.**

> The way I'm imagining it is some very very deep cavern that holds all of the planet atmosphere (doesn't have to be more then a single room sized area at the bottom of it that's in the "goldielocks zone") yet once you walk the thousands of step outside said cavern your technically in space as your outside the body atmosphere, I don't care if the journey will be years of walking uphill or that once upside the very small starting area you can't survive without a spacesuit.

To get an atmospheric composition that has free oxygen you need to have an ecosystem creating and using it. so just a single room would not do. https://www.britannica.com/topic/evolution-of-the-atmosphere-1703862. The only known way to create free oxygen naturally is through photosynthesis. Therefore the ecosystem needs to be exposed to the sunlight and therefore be on the surface. And so the atmosphere has to be at sufficient pressure on the surface.

To hold on to an atmosphere on geologic time scales a body needs to have a magnetosphere. https://www.nasa.gov/press-release/nasas-maven-reveals-most-of-mars-atmosphere-was-lost-to-space This comes from a active dynamo in a liquid interior that can carry a current. This means that the had to have enough time to develop life on it's surface and still have a liquid mantle. This also means that this body will have plate tectonics. And any body with plate tectonics will have a limit to how large a mountain can get before it would become to heavy to support by the plates and sink down. on top of this. Having an ecosystem means that there is an active cycle of liquid (water on earth). This cycle would continuously erode any mountain forming.

You are looking for an earth like atmosphere existing on a planet for a similar amount of time as earth. With plate tectonics like earth. That needs a size similar to earth. It is far from possible on earth so even in the most favourable of conditions you would still not be able to get a natural planet where you could live and then walk to space.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe, with a smaller planet.

On earth, the legally defined area of space is the [Karman line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A1rm%C3%A1n_line) where you can't fly around with just aeronautics. This is at 100 kilometers. This is far too high for you to reach with a mountain.

[On Mars there are much larger mountains, two and a half times as large](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olympus_Mons). With a moderate atmosphere you could have a low enough gas pressure that it was impossible to fly using air at the top of the mountain, but a high enough gas pressure that at the base and below the base you could breathe somewhat.

Notably, if there was gas in an underground cabin, the gas could 'walk' to the surface as well. Gravity would even it out. You need enough gas on the surface so that the cabin stays filled up. It might help to have a large meteor scar that dug a deep hole into the planet, a kilometer or two, but you'd still need a lot of air.

You could make the air a bit thin, but there may still be a bit of a gap. Here's where flexible definitions come in.

In terms of how space is defined, there's no hard line on this. It depends on the power of your aircraft, politics, and how much heating they can endure. Presumably on your planet, things are such that planes can't fly effectively at 22 kilometers. Your person can walk to the legally defined place of space.

Comment: The hard science tag requires answers with evidence & citations, so some links are expected, a star trek photo (your one link) doesn't really cut it.

Comment: From internet "The highest mountain on Mars is also the highest mountain and volcano in the entire solar system. It is called Olympus Mons and is 16 miles (24 kilometers) high which makes it about three times higher than Mt. Everest."

Comment: I fixed the link.

Answer (score -1):

Thursday, Sept. 23 2021.  Part two of my answer, which got too long for this site's limits.

Recommendation Two B.

I note that all spherical astronomical objects rotate, and so they are not perfectly spherical but actually oblate spheriods, bulging around the equators.  How much they bulge depends on how massive they are and how intense their gravity is, what materials they are made of, and how fast they rotate.

As I wrote above, Earth has a mean radius of 6,371 kilometers.  Since Earth is an oblate spheroid its polar radius is 6,356.752  kilometers, and its equatorial radius is 6,378.137 kilometers.  That is a difference of about 21.385 kilometers, which is about 2.5 times the scale height of Earth's atmosphere (about 8.5 kilometers).

So it is easy to image an Earth like planet which rotates much faster and is  much more oblate and has a radius atleast 100 kilometers or more greater at the equator than at the poles.  Such a planet should look almost perfectly spherical when seen from space.

Unfortunately for your story, people can breath just as well at sea level on the equator as at sea level at the north pole.  The atmosphere of the Earth also bulges due to the Earth's rotation.

Recommendation Two C.

There is another way that a roughly spherical planet can bulge, and that is a frozen tidal bulge.  And apparently not only science fiction writers, but even some scientists, thought that the atmosphere would not follow the  frozen tidal bulge, thus making it possible to walk from atmosphere to vacuum.

Calculating and predicting the precise orbit of the Moon is very complicated, since many factors affect the accuracy of calculations and predictions.  Astronomer Peter Andreas Hansen (1795-1874) claimed in 1854 that the Moon had an enormous bulge, like a giant mountain, facing the Earth.  And it was spectulated that all the air and water on the Moon was on the far side, hidden from sight, which was much lower in elevation.

Professor Simon Newcomb (1835-1909) showed that the Moon could not be nearly as egg shaped as claimed.

[https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00033798400200361](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/5407/why-is-mauna-kea-taller-than-the-maximum-height-possible-on-earth)

In recent decades, a fictional world has had a somewhat similar shape, jinx in the kNown worlds series by Larry Niven.

> The world is a satellite of a gas giant named Binary in the Sirius A system, and is home to a human colony. Jinx is six times more massive than Earth, and very dense, with a surface gravity of about 1.78 times Earth gravity. Its nickel-iron core is half the diameter of the world, the rest being rocky mantle and crust. Its most distinctive feature is its shape, that of a prolate spheroid (a rugby-ball or egg-shape). The shape of Jinx was fixed when it was in a close orbit to its primary, leading to tidal forces strong enough to produce this shape. Over time, tidal effects have caused Jinx to recede from its primary, while at the same time the planet has cooled and become more rigid, retaining its distorted shape. The extreme variations in altitude caused by this unusual shape have resulted in five distinct environmental zones.
>
> Along the meridian, where the atmosphere is thickest, runs a narrow band of high-pressure not suitable for human habitation. On either side of the meridian are two zones or bands where the atmosphere is suitable for human habitation. These are known as the East Band (home to the well developed colony), and the West Band (still a developing frontier). The "tips" of the spheroid are the East End and West End, which stick out of the planet's atmosphere into the vacuum of space. This makes the ends uninhabitable, but excellent for vacuum industries.
>
> In order for the crust to vary in altitude relative to the ocean and the atmosphere, the body has to be rigid enough to retain its shape under its own gravity. Jinx has a distinct lack of radioactive materials, so that the it would cool more quickly and become more rigid. There are also frequent earthquakes as Jinx' own gravity tries to draw it into hydrostatic equilibrium, in which the force of gravity is normal to the surface at every point. It is not clear whether rock could actually be rigid enough to retain such a deviation from equilibrium over geologic time scales.

[https://larryniven.fandom.com/wiki/Jinx](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5848/can-mountains-on-earth-grow-higher-than-49-000-feet-15-000-m)

If the Jinxian atmosphere has the same scale height as Earth's atmosphere, a distance of 100 to 200 kilometers at each end would be about 11 to 24 times the scale height of the atmosphere.  So if the diameter of Jinx was about 200 to 400 kilometers longer thorugh the ends than across the meridian, it would go from breathable atmoshere to a density as thin as at the Karmen line, or possibly much thinner, while the planet would still look almost spherical from the side.

So there are two questions.

One) Could rocks be rigid enough to maintain such high frozen tidal bulges at the two ends?

Two) Would the shape of the atmopshere follow the shape of the frozen tidal bulges and have the same density at ground level everywhere?

Or would the shape of the atmosphere be a spherical shape centered on the center of gravity of the planet, making the two ends stick out into outer space?  The frozen tidal bulges would not be maintained by the rotation of Jinx, so that rotation would not push air toward the two ends of Jinx?

Or whould the shape of the atmosphere be somewhat between those two extrmes due to various forces acting on it?

A world which almost entirely iron core with a very, very thin crust and mandle might be able to maintain such a shape better than a world with a normal amountof crust and mantle.

There are likely to many worlds with frozen tidal bulges.

I will return later with more suggestions.

[Added 10-21-21]

Here are some more obsrvations.

Venus has a maximum surface relief of about 13 kilometers, which is about 0.8176 of the scale height of it's atmosphere of 15.9 kilometers.

Earth has an elevation range of about 19.777 kilometers, which is 2.3268 of its atmospheric scale height of 8.5 kilometers.

Mars has an elevation range of about 29,400 kilometers, which is 2.6486 of its atmospheric scale height of 11.1 kilometers.

What did I say was the minimum possible atmospheric density which could be breathable for humans?

Possibly as low as 61 mm Hg or 81.13266 mbar to 69 millimeters of mercury (mm Hg) or 91.99229 mbar.

And what was the lowest altitude which some people suggested for the Karmen line of planet Earth, the edge of outer space?

About 70 to 80 kilometers.  So I wrote:

> I note that 8 times 8.5 is 68. An altitude of 68 kilometers would be about 8 times the scale height of Earth's atmosphere and would have a pressure of about 0.3401895 mb.

61 to 69 mm HG or 81.13266 to 91.99229 mb.  And that is about 238.49 to 270.414 times a pressure of 0.3401895 mb.

So what scale height is need to reduce atmospheric pressure by 238.49 to 270.414 times.  One scale height changes atmospheric presssure by *e*, which is about 2.71828.  So 2 scale heights (sh) changes pressure by 7.389 times, 3 sh changes pressure by 20.085 times, 4 sh changes pressure by 54.598 times, 5 sh changes pressure by 148.41265 times, and 6 sh changes pressure by 403.427 times, which should be more than enough to go from the lowest atmospheric pressure breathable by humans to the highest pressure in the lowest suggested Karmen line border of outer space.

And an altitude difference of 6 scale heights is 2.545 times the altitude difference on Earth with Earth's surface gravity, geological forces, and srength of surface materials, and it is 2.648 times the altitude difference on Mars with Mars's surface grvity, geological forces, and strength of surface materials.

So possibly you might want to consider whether it is possible for an Earth like planet to have a difference between its lowest and hightest elevations which is 6 scale heights of the atmosphere and 2 to 3 times as great as on Earth.

Can granite, basalt,  or other rocks be strong enough.  Can iron be strong enough?

if the answer to either question is yes, the problem may be solved.

Also see this question:

https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/20242/why-is-olympus-mons-the-largest-volcano-in-the-whole-solar-system

And the other sources it links to.

Recommendation Three.

Or possibly you might want to make the highest mountain on your planet out of much stronger material that Earth is made of, so that the highest mountain top on your planet can be much higher above the lowest pit on the planet's surface.

And where is such material that is stronger than granite and other rock?

Earth has a lot of it, an entire core made of iron nickel alloy, and all terrestrial type planets also do.

As we all know, if two planets are made of the same average materials the more massive planet will be more dense, since its greater gravity will compress its materials and make them denser than their natural density.

Earth has a mass of 1 Earth mass and has an average density 5.514 grams per cupic centimeters.

Venus has a mass of 0.85 Earth mass and a density of 5.243 grams per cubic centimeters, 0.95 that of Earth.

Mars has a mass of 0.107 Earth mass and a density of 3.9335 grams per cubic centimeters, 0.71333 that of Earth.

The Moon has a mass of 0.0123 Earth mass and a density of 3.334 grams per cubic centimeters, 0.6046 that of Earth.

Since Mercury has a mass intermediate between those of the Moon and Mars, it should have a density intermediate between those of the Moon and Mars.

Mercury has a mass of 0.55 Earth mass and a density of 5.427 grams per cubic centimeters, 0.984 that of Earth.

The average density of Mercury is greater than that of Mars and even greater than that of Venus.  And that is because the dense nickel iron core of Mercury is a much larger proportion of the volume of Mercury than in other planets.

> Geologists estimate that Mercury's core occupies about 55% of its volume; for Earth this proportion is 17%. Research published in 2007 suggests that Mercury has a molten core.[34][35] Surrounding the core is a 500–700 km (310–430 mi) mantle consisting of silicates.[36][37] Based on data from the Mariner 10 mission and Earth-based observation, Mercury's crust is estimated to be 35 km (22 mi) thick.[38]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_(planet)#Internal_structure

By comparison,Earth has a crust of about 35 kilometers deep and a mantle down to about 2,890 kilomters, then the outer core down to about 5,150 kilometers  and the inne core down to the center.

What we would need would be a planet with a much thinner crust and mantle over a large core.  Possibly the planet formed several times the size of the Earth and was struck by another forming planet, and lost most of its material including almost all of its mantle and crust.

So it might have a crust and mantle only 100 kilometers deep over its iron core.  And then somehow it must have collided with another mostly iron body that had a diameter of several hundred kilometers.

Possibly a chance encounter resulted in the planet capturing the body in a very close and retrograde orbit.  Moons in retro grade orbits around their planets slowly spiral inwards and crash into their planets after billions or trillions of years.  So you would want the smaller object to be captured in a retrograde orbit that was very close to the planet so it would spiral in very rapidly after only millions of years.

And then the smaller iron body would land on the planet and sink into the crust and mantle, gradually shoving aside the less dense matter of the crust and mantle until it came to rest on the iron core of the planet.

How wide would the smaller object have to be to stick up through the crust and mantle and stand at least about 6 scale heights above the surface?

Earth's atmosphere has a scale height of 8.5 kilometers, so with that atmospheric scale height the smaller object would have to stick up at least about 51  kilometers.

If the scale height is 5 kilometters the iron object would have to stick up about 30 kilometers.

If the scale height is 6 kilometers it would have to stick up 36 kilometers.

If the scale height is 7 kilometers it would have to stick up 42 kilometers.

If the scale height is 8 kilometers it would have to stick up 48 kilometers.

If the scale height is 9 kilometers it would have to stick up 54 kilometers.

If the scale height is 10 kilometers it would have to stick up 60 kilometers.

If the scale height is 11 kilometers it would have to stick up 66 kilometers.

If the scale height is 12 kilometers it would have to stick up 72 kilometers.

And if the crust and mantle of the planet are about 100 kilometers thick, we have to add 100 kilometers to the diameter of the object to allow for it resting on the outer edge of the iron core of the planet, thus making the total diameter of the object at least about 130 to 172 kilometers above the surface of the iron core.

But I suspect that during millions and billions of years the iron will slowly flow downward, turning the originally roughly spherical iron object into a rather flat cone.  Thus the original roughly spherical object has to have been several times wider than 130 to 172 kilometers in order to still be that tall after flattening out over eons of time.

There is just one little problem with this.

The landing.

When a large iron asteroid lands on the surface of the planet there is likely to be a very big crash.  If the planet and the iron asteroid are shattered into gazillions of pieces and slowly reform into a single world, that will be no good.  The irron core, the crust, and the mantle fragments will be all mixed together, and will not be strong enough to support mountains tens of kilometers high.  And over eons of time they will stratify, with the iron sinking to the core of the new planet making the surface material even less likely to be strong enough for such high elevations.

And if the collison heats both bodies up into molten lava, they will mix
and the heavier iron nickel will gradually sink the core and the lighter mantle and crust materials will gradually rise to the top, and the materials available for building mountains will be no stronger than on Earth.

Possibly an advanced civilization might have gently placed a vast iron mountain on the surface of the planet, using space ships with anti gravity drive and tractor beams to lower it into posiiton, avoiding a tremendous explosion that might mix the different materials together.

Recommendation Four.

An equatorial Ridge.

Iapetus, a moon of Saturn, has a massive equatorial ridge of mountains running three quarters of the way around its equator.

Imagine that a large planet, several times as massive as Earth, is struck by another planet and they explode.  Almost all the mass of the two planets is lost.  But most of their heavier iron cores remains close to the collision sie and gradually reforms into a neq planet, almost entirely nickel iron.

Then another, much smaller world, collides with the mostly iron planet and knocks a lot of iron off the planet.  Much of that iron remains in orbit around the mostly iron planet.  Over time, gravitational forces pull those iron particles into a thin but wide ring orbiting over the planet's equator.

And if many of those particles happen to be orbiting in a retrograde orbit, and are close enough to the planet, they will gradually spiral inwards and eventually land along the equator of the planet.  Over thousands and millions of years, vast amounts of iron chucks will rain down on the equator and pile up into an equatorial ridge.

Since iron is stronger than stone, an iron equatorial ridge could be much higher than a stoney equatorial ridge.  And possibly later impacts will bring much stoney matter to the planet and it will be covered with a layer of stone several kilometers thick, but with the iron ridge still sticking up tens of kilometers above the ground at its base.

Recommendation Five.

And of course it is always possible for a writer to fake it.

If it seems impossible to have a planet with sufficient elevation difference to have a breathable atmosphere in the lowest hollows and air as thin as the lowest possible Karmen line at the top of the highest mountains, a writer can always try to write something convincing that will obscure the fact that it is impossible.

Imagine a tidally lock planet, which rotates with a rotational period the same length as its orbital period around the star.  Thus once side of the planet will always face the star, and will have eternal day and great heat, and the other side will always face away from the star and will have eternal night and great cold.

And it is usally imagined that such a world could not have life because all its air and water would boil away on the day side and flow to the night side, and there cool off, condense, and freeze solid, and never return to the day side again.

One side of the planet would be a hot desert without air or water, the other side would be a cold, frozen desert without air or liquid water.

Temperatures might be right for life in the twilight zone between the hot side and the frozen side, but neither air nor water would stay there permanently - it would all eventually freeze solid on the night side.

And there is some controversey over whether that would actually be the case, or whether a decently dense atmosphere and hydrosphere would spread the heat evenly over the planet.

But let's assume that the planet has a scorching hot day side and a freezing cold night side.

If the planet has any vulcanism, volcanoes might emit some gas, giving the planet a very thin atmosphere constantly freezing over on the night side.  Thus there would always be a very week wind from the hotter day side to the cold night side.

Triton,the moon of Neptune, has a very thin atmosphere, with a pressue of 14 microbars, 14 millionths of a bar. But there is evidence of winds on Triton.

> In 1989 Voyager 2 discovered that near the surface there are winds blowing to the east or north-east with a speed of about 5–15 m/s.[1](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/5407/why-is-mauna-kea-taller-than-the-maximum-height-possible-on-earth) Their direction was determined by observations of dark streaks located over the southern polar cap, which generally extend from the south-west to north-east. These winds are thought to be related to the sublimation of nitrogen ice from the southern cap as there was summer in the southern hemisphere in 1989.[1](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/5407/why-is-mauna-kea-taller-than-the-maximum-height-possible-on-earth) The gaseous nitrogen moves northward and is deflected by the Coriolis force to the east forming an anticyclone near the surface. The tropospheric winds are capable of moving material of over a micrometre in size thus forming the streaks.[1](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/5407/why-is-mauna-kea-taller-than-the-maximum-height-possible-on-earth)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_Triton

So no matter how thin the gases on the planet are, I would expect there to be some wind blowing from the hot side to the cold side.

And maybe near the terminator there could be a deep valley or crater or depression heated by volcanoes which produce some gas, and with enough light for plants to grow and convert carbon dioxide into oxygen.

And the atmosphere could be be barely dense enough for humans to beath.  And air that rises over the top of the depression would be caught by the wind from the hot side and blown to the cold side.

Saying that would not solve the problem of the highest mountains being at least 6 atmosphere scale heights, and thus tens of kilometers, higher than the deepest parts of that depression.  There would still be the problem of whether any form of stone would be strong enough for such great differences in elevation.

if any form of stone has sufficient strength for an elevation difference of 6 scale heights and tens of kilometers, there is no need to evoke the wind blowing away all the gases which rise out of the depression anyway.  And such a wind will not eliminate the need for at least six scale heights of elevation difference on the planet.

So it doesn't make any difference.

But like a stage magician, a writer can use indirection to perform an illusion.  If characters talk about the wind from the hot side blowing away all the gases which rise above the rim of the depression, readers might get the impression that there would be a sharp boundry between air barely dense enough to breath and air so thin it was almost a vacuum.

the readers might not realize that the atmosphere must have a gradual pressure diminuation with height and accept that the wind might cause a sharp cut off in pressure at a certain altitude.

Recomendation Six.

A Really Frightening Scenario.

And another possiblilty is that atmosphere about a certain level is stripped away by the greater gravity of a neighboring astronomical body.  Of course the big problemw with that is getting the neighboring astronomical body to be massive enough and/or close enough to take away atmosphere down to the altitude of even the tallest possible mountains.

So possibly the planet is orbited by a primordial black hole at a low altitude.  Or if the primordial black hole is more massive than the planet, the planet will orbit the primordial black hole.

And that sounds like another case where a writer might be able to talk a good talk and use indirection to keep the readers from realizing that it wouldn't work in real life the way it would in the story.

Added Oct. 26,2021.

Here is a link to a question about the possible heights of mountains.

https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/47211/why-do-venus-earth-and-mars-have-tall-volcanoes-but-the-moon-mercury-and-io

And links to many other questions and answers and articles.

https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/20242/why-is-olympus-mons-the-largest-volcano-in-the-whole-solar-system

https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/917/does-a-planets-mass-or-gravity-affect-the-height-of-its-mountains

https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/9745/how-high-can-a-mountain-possibly-get

https://www.newscientist.com/article/mg22430002-500-glacial-buzz-saw-takes-mountains-out-at-the-knees/

https://arstechnica.com/science/2020/06/plate-tectonics-vs-erosion-what-sets-the-height-of-a-mountain-range/

https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/5407/why-is-mauna-kea-taller-than-the-maximum-height-possible-on-earth

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5848/can-mountains-on-earth-grow-higher-than-49-000-feet-15-000-m

And those may help in deciding what type of world might have a maximum elevation range of at least 6 atmospheric scale heights and thus at least several tens of kilometers.