# If Earth's atmosphere was 100% oxygen, which settlement would be the lowest habitable one?

Tags: biology, atmosphere, habitability, medical, oxygen

If we replace all other gases of the Earth's atmosphere by oxygen so that we have 1 atm oxygen at sea level, which one would be the lowest (either permanently or for a certain amount of time) habitable settlement or altitude on Earth? The 0.21 atm oxygen level would be at airliner cruise altitude and the summit of Everest would be habitable as would all summits of the Earth's highest mountains.

The highest permanent settlement is La Rinconada in Peru at 17,000 ft elevation. Would it be habitable if the atmosphere was 100% oxygen? At that altitude, atmospheric pressure is a bit more than half that at sea level, at 100% oxygen would those be low enough oxygen levels not to be toxic? And what means could humans use to reach lower elevations without a pressure suit? Rather than altitude climbing records, people would likely go after depth descent records.

Comment: *"If we replace all other gases of the Earth's atmosphere by oxygen"* . . . then all land plants die. Oxygen inhibits photosynthesis. A buffer like nitrogen is essential.

Comment: i think you are asking two distinct questions here. the q for means to explore lower regions should be separate.

Comment: @Mathaddict Not quite. My question is more on current settlements or mountain camps rather than actual pressure. I knew that _approximately_ 0.6 bar is the maximum oxygen pressure one can live in, but what effects exactly would that have on someone living in La Rinconada, where the pressure is about that, that is what I wonder.

Comment: if you are wondering about the effects of oxygen toxicity, you should ask about that.

Comment: @ths I'm interested in the grey zone, not enough oxygen to be _that_ toxic, but not low enough that a settlement could be habitable permanently.

Comment: @Giovanni  My answer to this question https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/213913/walking-to-space discusses the thinnest atmosphere that humans could breath if it was almost all oxygen & explains that some nitrogen, carbon dioxide, and water vapor is also needed.  And it quotes from a source mentioning the maximum pressure of oxygen.

Comment: Agree on ctv (already answered) *and* I've put a +1.. welcome @Giovanni, interesting subject. Thanks for provoking some great links !

Comment: @M.A.Golding The 70 mmHg value isn't true like this, for it ignores the fact that humans cannot inhale below a pressure around 88 mmHg (1.7 psi). At 88mmHg you can hold your breath with much force, below you'd be forced to exhale and would be unable to inhale even pure oxygen due to the too low pressure. You also got Earth's atmosphere's scale height wrong. 14.7/e=5.408 psi, which you find at an altitude of ~7.7 km, not 8.5.

Comment: Can't happen.  In 100% oxygen, things that are not ordinarily considered combustible become combustible.  There would be continent-spanning fires until the oxygen levels dropped to something more reasonable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Short answer 17000 Ft. 0.5 atm

So pressure around 0.5 atm. Not really survivable, mainly due to the reactivity of oxygen. The human body probably wouldn't work (fats and molecules breaking down slowly). Though this is borderline I think.

Reddit article for fun:
https://www.reddit.com/r/Physics/comments/g0lki/would_it_be_possible_to_breathe_in_a_room_at_2/

### Bad idea...

https://science.howstuffworks.com/question493.htm
Based on this article it seems that in general it should be avoided, especially under high pressure (and the fire risk would be HUGE).

However Astronauts and scuba divers do breathe pure oxygen at lower pressures for longer times.

According to: [https://airandspace.si.edu/exhibitions/apollo-to-the-moon/online/astronaut-life/breathing-drinking.cfm#:~:text=The%20atmosphere%20in%20the%20Apollo,by%20canisters%20of%20lithium%20hydroxide](https://airandspace.si.edu/exhibitions/apollo-to-the-moon/online/astronaut-life/breathing-drinking.cfm#:%7E:text=The%20atmosphere%20in%20the%20Apollo,by%20canisters%20of%20lithium%20hydroxide).

> The atmosphere in the Apollo spacecraft was 100% oxygen, at a pressure
> of five pounds per square inch. The oxygen system constantly added
> fresh oxygen to the cabin to replenish that breathed by the crew.
> Carbon dioxide exhaled by the astronauts was removed by canisters of
> lithium hydroxide.

For those like me... that is 0.34023 atm

### Elevation

According to this calculator: https://www.mide.com/air-pressure-at-altitude-calculator

The elevation would be around 8000-8500 meters (26246. feet minimum).

Everest is 29,032 ft or 8,848.86 meters.

So Everest height (No civilization as we cannot function at that height right now)

### On Normal Earth

This altitude is in the death range of Everest.

See: https://wonderopolis.org/wonder/How-Dangerous-Is-Mount-Everest%E2%80%99s-Death-Zone

> This may lead to high altitude cerebral edema (HACE). HACE can cause nausea and vomiting. Even more dangerous, it can lead to difficulty thinking. In the death zone, climbers can forget where they are or even have hallucinations

So technically you can survive, but civilization would not work (on Normal Earth).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_highest_settlements):

Highest settlement
4,410 metres (14,470 ft)    Dingboche   Nepal

Way way lower than 8000m

### Option

Just make the world have lower ATM?

### Other problems

Also, side note, if there was no water in the air we would not be able to grow anything and wouldn't be able to live. We need to get hydrogen from somewhere, and if water isn't stable in the air (for some reason) hydrogen just leaves the atmosphere to space (Earth would not be able to keep hydrogen, see mars).
Slowly, but surely, Earth would lose hydrogen for water. Earth would become uninhabitable.

Even if we aren't losing hydrogen to space (a slow procedure), water would all evaporate. All of it. 100% oxygen means zero humidity. Zero humidity means everything evaporates. Even solid ice would slowly disappear due to the lack of ANY water in the air. Civilization (especially before technology) is completely based on the prevalence of water. (Cities were all on water or rivers).

### Temporary Oxygen?

Thus, long-term, no where is habitable unless the air turned to oxygen at one moment, but wasn't constantly maintained at 100% oxygen. That would be a much much trickier situation, but one where somewhere would inevitably end up habitable (though most of the world would still burn down).

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding! This is a very good answer (+1), but you might want to reorganize the presentation, and you should lead with a brief synopsis of "not below 0.5 atmospheres" so people know you have the final answer.

Comment: It's weird the WP page doesn't mention Lobuche as the highest settlement in Nepal. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lobuche,_Nepal Gorakshep is even higher, but not inhabited year-round.

Comment: Ok, I'll add a small header at the top

Answer (score 2):

The toxic partial pressure of oxygen for long term exposure is about 0.5atm (according to https://socratic.org/questions/what-partial-pressure-of-oxygen-is-toxic). That means that the air would get toxic below about 5700m above sea level. (calculated here: https://www.mide.com/air-pressure-at-altitude-calculator)

17000 ft seem to be about 5200m, so this would still be below safe altitude.

Comment: Alright, but what effects would a human living at 17,000 ft (La Rinconada) show compared to a human living at 17,500 ft (Everest Base Camp, which should be survivable at 100% oxygen)?

Comment: you can read all about that at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen_toxicity btw. 17500ft is still below 5700m.

Comment: BTW, this condition means minimum altitude to avoid toxicity is barely below the "death zone" where even breathing pure oxygen doesn't prevent pulmonary edema due to the low pressure -- the habitable band would be less than a kilometer, from 5700 m to around 6 km.

Comment: @ZeissIkon from what i'm reading, the death zone only refers to O2 partial pressure.

Comment: Based on my (admittedly limited) reading, the "death zone" is where altitude sickness will eventually kill you even if you're breathing pure oxygen at enough partial pressure to keep your brain oxygenated (i.e. below the Armstrong limit).  Altitude sickness, at its core, is pulmonary edema, brought about by too much pressure difference between body fluids and the air in the lungs.

Comment: Without fire or just-as-risky alternative heating, nothing even close to 5700m is habitable. Truly, you need to be at sea level in the tropics.